# C++ function`s declaration and definition are different but it works well

Tags: c++, gcc, g++

I'm writing some C++ code
And I found a very strange thing
Like below code, it works well even though a function's declaration and definition are different

Does anyone know how can this is possible?
build cmd : `g++ main.cpp foo.cpp`

```
// main.cpp
#include <iostream>

char foo();

int main() {
    foo();
}

// foo.cpp
#include <iostream>

void foo() {
    std::cout << "I'm foo" << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately "work well" is one of the possible outcomes of [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Comment: This _works_ likely because the x86 calling convention passes integer return values in registers (namely, `rax`).

Comment: Thank you guys, I will check what you've mentioned

Comment: Why [tag:c]???....

Comment: Add `-Wall -W -Werror` to your  build command and see...

Comment: @LPs likely to be no error unless `-flto` also given

Comment: It still works well with `g++ -Wall -W -Werror -flto main.cpp foo.cpp` in x86 machine  
(gcc is same)

Comment: You have undefined behavior, there's really not much more to say than that. If you want to ask about why a specific implementation (compiler and specific version of it) and how it works on the assembler level then please edit your question to add the GCC version and tell us your target platform (OS, version of it, and more importantly your CPU). And as mentioned, the seemingly "working" part is very likely because of you not attempting to use the "return value" of the function. You might also want to take a look at the generated assembler code for `main` to see what's happening.

Comment: As you are not entertaining the return type in main(), it works.

It is base on compilation rules as well. But when I compiled got below error:

1>Temp.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "char __cdecl foo(void)" (?foo@@YADXZ) referenced in function _main
1>  Hint on symbols that are defined and could potentially match:
1>    "void __cdecl foo(void)" (?foo@@YAXXZ)

Comment: I understood it is undefined behavior already, I just did more cuz Mannoj and M.M suggest new options, anyway thank you everyone, I learned much

Comment: What do you mean by "works well"? What did you expect it to do and why? And if you don't have something specific you expected it to do, how can you say it works well?

Answer (score 1):

The compilation is successful as you are not entertaining the return type in main(), it works. 
Also as you have not used the return type of function. It neglects the return type there.
It is based on compilation rules as well.

The linker might not allow and throw an error.
I am using VS2019 and I got below linking error (error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol ).